# HP Envy Printer 5540 series showing Ink Cartridges error

Tags: printer, ink, hp-envy

My HP printer orders new ink via the Internet when needed via 'HP Instant Ink'. I installed a new colour cartridge which had been sent to me when the previous cartridge ran low. The printer then resumed printing successfully. However the following morning the printer showed the error:

> Ink Cartridges Problem. Remove and reinstall the indicated ink cartridge [...]  if this message continues to appear, replace the indicated ink cartridge.

The issue is with the new colour cartridge - as far as I can tell the black one is fine. I have removed and then reinstalled the cartridge several times. I have also turned the printer on and off again. The problem persists. I don't have another colour cartridge to try as a replacement, as the printer 'orders' ink when it needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the "indicated ink cartridge" is the same as the one you just installed. As it's a brand new HP cartridge, contact you local HP office for a replacement. Explain the problem to them and they will send a new one under warranty.

EDIT

@eleventhdoctor added 2 facts:

- Unlike some printers the HP Envy 5541 will run on its black cartridge only. Remove the faulty colour cartridge and the printer will automatically switch to 'Single Cartridge Mode'.
- HP UK's telephone no. is **0207 6600596**

Comment: This is good advice: HP Instant Ink means I have a contract with them and am entitled to support.